# What's a modern equivalent of "fie on thee"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, archaicisms

Is there a modern equivalent to the archaic expression "fie on thee"?

I'm aware of expressions such as "damn you" and the like, but I'm looking for something less strong.

Comment: How strong do you think 'fie on thee' was?

Comment: @tunny Not very, many dictionaries define it as something along the lines of *used to express mild disgust, disapprobation, annoyance, etc.*.

Comment: "Darn you!  Darn you to heck!"

Comment: damn you isn't all that strong anymore.

Comment: @Oldcat It depends on the group of people, I suppose. Even "fuck you" isn't all that strong in some groups, but it's certainly more taboo than "fie on thee".

Comment: How about: "Forget you!"

Comment: I still remember "wae te scelera" from Catullus:) And then there's the "passer" poem...

Comment: Peter, I wouldn't rely on the consensus of dictionaries. After all, how many of them do you really think would us "fuck you" as a definition???

Comment: I think a more modern equivalent is "Shame on you".

Comment: @rogermue - it doesn't seem that fie had an actual meaning, at least from Etymonline. Did it acquire one sometime later?

Comment: @medica As others I don't know anything of the original meaning, except that it is an expression of disgust and displeasure.The German equivalent is pfui. German DWDS which  contains the etymological dictionary of Pfeiffer only gives the information that the sound existed already in Latin and Old Greek. Pfeiffer takes it the expression is "lautmalend", onomatopoetic, imitating a sound. But that doesn't tell much. What kind of sound is there to imitate?? I always guessed the word had the meaning "(it) stinks", maybe said to a dog meaning don't eat it. Only a guess.

Comment: "Shame on you"?

Comment: The psalms in the Book of Common Prayer were translated from the Hebrew by Miles Coverdale in 1535. Psalm 40  has the phrase "Fie upon thee, fie upon thee."  The King James version of 1611, and nearly all modern versions translate that phrase "Aha, aha".   So maybe fie upon thee in the early sixteenth century meant what aha means now. Or maybe  Coverdale may have  made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

According to Etymology online, *fie* (late 13c) was

> a general sound of disgust that seems to have developed independently in many languages.

So, today, it seems a good correlation would be the *tsk-tsk* sound one makes with their tongue on hearing something they disapprove of. (Maybe the Brits say *Tut!*, but I don't know. I think of Winnie the Pooh when I hear that.)

Another exclamation still used for the same purpose is

> pshaw (interj.) exclamation of contempt or rejection, by 1670s.

I've heard people "say" *pffft!* or *hmmph!* for the same reason.

Comment: I rarely address down voters, but to you, I say *pffft!*

Answer (score 0):

The only response I can think of that isn't very strong that I have actually heard a lot is to thank the other person very sarcastically. eg:

"Thanks ... **a lot**!"

(delivered with no smile and unwavering eye-contact)

Answer (score 0):

How about using "piffle" as a synonym for "fie" -- that's still used, though admittedly less common and arguably old-fashioned.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

To me it is a mild curse. "Fie on you" means something in-between "a curse on you" and "I don't care what you say, you rascal."